# php Find if array value is bigger then a variable

Tags: php, arrays

Hello a am trying to create a function that will return me a value from the array if the value is bigger the a variable.
 the array is

```
[0] => Array ( [payment] => 1 [amount] => 100) 
[1] => Array ( [payment] => 2 [amount] => 300 ) 
[2] => Array ( [payment] => 3 [amount] => 800 )
```

$variable =  350;

I need to get the payment value if is bigger then 300 amount .
what I mean is to get back the value payment = 2. that is bigger then 300 and smaller the 800.

Thanks

Comment: what have you tried? Please try something. That's how you learn. Receiving the full code with *no* attempt on your end does not do you any good

Comment: You want all payment values greater than 300 or you want if at least one of them is greater than 300?

Comment: Please, explain your question a little bit more.

Comment: Isn't it payment = 3 you are looking for? It should be larger than 350, that means key 2 of array or payment =3?

Comment: I am sorry I did not find any answer for this. I was looking for 5 hours for a result for this. sorry about my English

Comment: Dani, this looks a lot like classwork, right?  What did you do to find the answer two?  You looked at a row, then checked to see if the amount was larger than the variable.  So you need to search for a way to loop through an array, then compare that value to the variable.  If you get code that you think is a start, edit that into your answer above and you might get more help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said that if you are searching fr 350 it need to return record of amount 300, that means:-

***You are searching for nearest amount first and then get `payment` value of that corresponding amount***

Do like below:-

```
<?php


$array = Array(
            '0' => Array ( 'payment' => 1, 'amount' => 100) ,
            '1' => Array ( 'payment' => 2, 'amount' => 300 ) ,
            '2' => Array ( 'payment' => 3, 'amount' => 800 )
        );

function getNearest($search, $arr) {
   $closest = null;
   foreach ($arr as $item) {
      if ($closest === null || abs($search - $closest) > abs($item - $search)) {
         $closest = $item;
      }
   }
   return $closest;
}

$key = array_search(getNearest(350, array_column($array,'amount')),array_column($array,'amount'));

echo $array[$key]['payment'];
```

Output:- https://eval.in/933225

Comment: @DaniEvanRubenstein  glad to help you :):)

Answer (score 0):

well ... Frankenstein is coming ! :)

```html
<?php
/*
 if Lazarus is dead .. i bring him alive,
 if Lazarus is wrong .. i'll fix it..
 and any Lazarus doesn't exist i'll invent one
                                                 .. with php,

 mi me mi !

*/
function myArray($ar){
 function searchx($n){
  if(($n['amount']>$GLOBALS['val_search_min'])and($n['amount']<$GLOBALS['val_search_max'])) return($n);
  //mofify the condition how you like ... i put    x>min and x<max     inside here!

 }
 $values=array_map("searchx", $ar);

 return array_filter($values);
}



$arrayx=Array(
 Array ('payment' => 1, 'amount' => 100),
 Array ('payment' => 2,'amount' => 300 ),
 Array ('payment' => 3,'amount' => 800 ),
 Array ('payment' => 2,'amount' => 200 ),
 Array ('payment' => 3,'amount' => 500 ),
 Array ('payment' => 2,'amount' => 400 ),
 Array ('payment' => 3,'amount' => 700 )
);

//a kind of interval:
$val_search_min=300;
$val_search_max=800;

$igotthese=myArray($arrayx);

echo('the result of my stupid function is:<pre>');
var_dump($igotthese);
echo('</pre>');
?>
```

the result i got here .. push **Run code snippet** :

```html
the result of my stupid function is:<pre>array(3) {
  [4]=>
  array(2) {
    ["payment"]=>
    int(3)
    ["amount"]=>
    int(500)
  }
  [5]=>
  array(2) {
    ["payment"]=>
    int(2)
    ["amount"]=>
    int(400)
  }
  [6]=>
  array(2) {
    ["payment"]=>
    int(3)
    ["amount"]=>
    int(700)
  }
}
</pre>
```